# Bitbucket endpoint for all Pull Requests assigned to a user?

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-api

Using the Bitbucket REST API, I’m looking for a way to get all pull requests that are assigned to a user. So far this endpoint: `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repository_name}/pullrequests/{pullrequest_id}?fields=reviewers` will show me the reviewer assigned to that specific pull request ID. Is there a way to do that, but not for a specific pull request, rather all pull requests assigned to a user?

Comment: Have you tried filtering `list pull requests`? https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro#filtering

Comment: This is something that I'd also like to know...

Answer (score 0):

[this API call](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-pullrequests-selected-user-get) worked for me in Bitbucket cloud.